# Creating a calendar event in Android, edit in iOS

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, calendar

I'm looking at adding a calendar event and then link that event for future edit or delete action. My app works in both Android and iOS.

If I create an event with Android Xamarin code the URI returned from ContentResolver.Insert looks like

content://com.android.calendar/events/3852

The problem is that URI is related to the device that created the account - it is not a unique URI that I can use on iOS - which expects the EkEvent to be a number.

So using Xamarin is it possible to create an event in Android, and then edit the same event in iOS?

Comment: if you need to identify what type of platform is making the request, you can use Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS to identify what platform type is being called, so if you need to make tweeks when is iOS, you can use that

Comment: for this to work the calendar on both devices would need to be tied to the same backing calendar.  Even then it seems like this would be an extremely brittle solution at best.